# ruby-opengl error on Windows

Tags: ruby, windows, opengl

I'm trying to set up Ruby with OpenGL on Windows. I installed the [pre-compiled ruby-opengl gem for Windows](http://rubyforge.org/frs/download.php/52687/ruby-opengl-0.60.1-x86-mswin32-ruby19.gem), and the install completed without errors, but when I try to run their `nehe_lesson02.rb` sample, I get the following error:

```
c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `require': 127: The specified procedure could not be found.   - c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ruby-opengl-0.60.1-x86-mswin32/lib/gl.so (LoadError)
from c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `rescue in require'
from c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:35:in `require'
from C:/Users/Jonathan/My Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/barberry/main.rb:8:in `<main>'
```

Would anyone who has managed to set up Ruby with OpenGL be willing to lend a few tips?

Comment: I spent a good deal of time trying to set up Ruby-OpenGL on Windows. It just didn't work, no matter what I tried. Neither that nor SDL seem to have any decent support anymore. You may have gotten farther than I did. I notice that your error referenced "gl.so". Isn't that a Linux library extension? Shouldn't you have a "gl.dll"?

Comment: Ah, that sucks. Yeah, I noticed that too - it looked like the installed gem contained gl.so, not gl.dll.